# Can I perform multiple assertions in pytest?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I'm using pytest for my selenium tests and wanted to know if it's possible to have multiple assertions in a single test?

I call a function that compares multiple values and I want the test to report on all the values that don't match up. The problem I'm having is that using "assert" or "pytest.fail" stops the test as soon as it finds a value that doesn't match up.

Is there a way to make the test carry on running and report on all values that don't match?

Comment: Can't you just build up a list of errors, then assert the list is empty?

Comment: I want to report on individual errors though, so that in the report it gives me a list of the values that didn't match

Comment: Umm... how does building up a list of the non-matches, then asserting that list is empty (in case of errors it won't be) - you'll then get the list as a "expected [] - got [1, 2, 7, 10]` or something not do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As Jon Clements commented, you can fill a list of error messages and then assert the list is empty, displaying each message when the assertion is false.

concretely, it could be something like that:

```
def test_something(self):
    errors = []

    # replace assertions by conditions
    if not condition_1:
        errors.append("an error message")
    if not condition_2:
        errors.append("an other error message")

    # assert no error message has been registered, else print messages
    assert not errors, "errors occured:\n{}".format("\n".join(errors))
```

The original assertions are replaced by `if` statements which append messages to an `errors` list in case condition are not met.
Then you assert the `errors` list is empty (an empty list is False) and make the assertion message contains each message of the `errors` list.

---

You could also make a test generator as described in the [nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators). I did not find any pytest doc which describes it, but I know that pytest handled this exactly the same manner as nose.

Answer (score 21):

[pytest-assume](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-assume) is *"a pytest plugin that allows multiple failures per test"*. Here's an example of how you would use it (taken from the `README`):

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(('x', 'y'), [(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)])
def test_simple_assume(x, y):
    pytest.assume(x == y)
    pytest.assume(True)
    pytest.assume(False)
```

Even though some of the assertions fail, they all get evaluated and reported:

```
======================================== FAILURES =========================================
_________________________________ test_simple_assume[1-1] _________________________________
>    pytest.assume(False)
test_assume.py:7

y          = 1
x          = 1
----------------------------------------
Failed Assumptions:1
_________________________________ test_simple_assume[1-0] _________________________________
>    pytest.assume(x == y)
test_assume.py:5

y          = 0
x          = 1
>    pytest.assume(False)
test_assume.py:7

y          = 0
x          = 1
----------------------------------------
Failed Assumptions:2
_________________________________ test_simple_assume[0-1] _________________________________
>    pytest.assume(x == y)
test_assume.py:5

y          = 1
x          = 0
>    pytest.assume(False)
test_assume.py:7

y          = 1
x          = 0
----------------------------------------
Failed Assumptions:2
================================ 3 failed in 0.02 seconds =================================
```

Comment: Just for others coming here and wondering about the different plugins, `pytest-assume` was forked from `pytest-expect`. Note also, `pytest-expect` is the earlier version of `pytest_check`. Both, `pytest-assume` and `pytest_check`, need to be installed.

Answer (score 5):

yet another library is available by the author of the 2017 Pragmatic book on pytest, Brian Okken.
https://pythontesting.net/books/pytest/
https://github.com/okken/pytest-check

```
import pytest_check as check

def test_example():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = [2, 4, 6]
    check.greater(a, b)
    check.less_equal(b, a)
    check.is_in(a, c, "Is 1 in the list")
    check.is_not_in(b, c, "make sure 2 isn't in list")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative approach called [Delayed assert](http://pythontesting.net/strategy/delayed-assert/), It pretty much similar to what @Tryph has provided, and gives better stack trace.

The [delayed-assert](https://pypi.org/project/delayed-assert/) package on PyPI implements this approach. See also the [pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert](https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert) repository on GitHub, or install from PyPI using:

```
pip install delayed-assert
```

You can use (possibly) any assertion library in combination with python-delayed-assert. Consider it more like a stack trace manager library rather than an assertion. Check [this](https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert/blob/master/ExampleUnittest.py) for example uses

This is how the error stack trace looks,

[image: https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert/raw/master/sample.jpg]

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can download the delayed_assert library? I've been looking around and haven't been able to find it

Comment: You don't need any library. Use this for reference https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert

Comment: Now it can be install with ```pip install https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rather simplistic approach:

```py
import pytest

def test_sample(texts):
    flag = True
    for text in texts:
        if text != "anything":
            flag = False
    if flag==False:
        pytest.fail("text did not match", pytrace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here using newer versions of pytest, there is built in parametrizing: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html . As it is showed in documentation, when using this your test will be divided in multiple tests. This example is extracted from there, one test is seen as three tests.

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert eval(test_input) == expected
```

Result:

```bash
$ pytest
=========================== test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.x.y, pytest-6.x.y, py-1.x.y, pluggy-1.x.y
cachedir: $PYTHON_PREFIX/.pytest_cache
rootdir: $REGENDOC_TMPDIR
collected 3 items

test_expectation.py ..F                                              [100%]

================================= FAILURES =================================
____________________________ test_eval[6*9-42] _____________________________

test_input = '6*9', expected = 42

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [("3+5", 8), ("2+4", 6), ("6*9", 42)])
    def test_eval(test_input, expected):
>       assert eval(test_input) == expected
E       AssertionError: assert 54 == 42
E        +  where 54 = eval('6*9')

test_expectation.py:6: AssertionError
========================= short test summary info ==========================
FAILED test_expectation.py::test_eval[6*9-42] - AssertionError: assert 54...
======================= 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.12s ========================
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use [pytest-check](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-check/)
2. Use [pytest-assume](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-assume/)
3. Use [pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#running-multiple-assert-statements-safely)

Other people have provided examples for the first two, I am going to discuss the last options.

The example provided in the [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#running-multiple-assert-statements-safely) is a little more elaborate. I am going to provide a simpler example.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Multiple independent asserts using class-scope fixture
"""

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def data():
    """
    Create data for test.

    Using scope=class, this fixture is created once per class. That
    means each test should exercise care not to alter the fixture data,
    or subsequent tests might fail.
    """
    fixture_data = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
    print(f"(data fixture created at {id(fixture_data)}) ", end="")
    return fixture_data


class TestItWithFailures:
    def test_a_value(self, data):
        assert data["a"] == 1
        # Modify the data will cause test failure in subsequent tests
        data["b"] = 200
        data["c"] = 300

    def test_b_value(self, data):
        # Failed because of previous modification
        assert data["b"] == 2

    def test_c_value(self, data):
        # Failed because of previous modification
        assert data["c"] == 3


class TestWithSuccess:
    def test_a_value(self, data):
        assert data["a"] == 1

    def test_b_value(self, data):
        assert data["b"] == 2

    def test_c_value(self, data):
        assert data["c"] == 3
```

#### Output

```
test_it.py::TestItWithFailures::test_a_value (data fixture created at 4366616320) PASSED
test_it.py::TestItWithFailures::test_b_value FAILED
test_it.py::TestItWithFailures::test_c_value FAILED
test_it.py::TestWithSuccess::test_a_value (data fixture created at 4372781312) PASSED
test_it.py::TestWithSuccess::test_b_value PASSED
test_it.py::TestWithSuccess::test_c_value PASSED
```

#### Notes

- Each class is a separate test, each function in the class is a separate assert. This way, we achieve multiple independent assertions.
- Take care not to alter the data fixture, or it will affect subsequent tests as seen in the `TestItWithFailures` class.