# Python unit test with condition for two results

Tags: python, testing

i have easy test for testing of content of variable

`self.assertEqual(t, b'wwe100.wwe.com')`

But i need to make `assertEqual` for several variants, like condition.
At least i alos need to have this `self.assertEqual(t, b'njpw100.njpw.org')` too. How can i do this ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This question should be asked on [so]

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple assertions with [pytest-assume](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-assume).

See this question: [Can I perform multiple assertions in pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896716/can-i-perform-multiple-assertions-in-pytest?rq=1)